# Why this body does not qualify as a valid maths question?

Tags: discussion, quality-filter

"Given $ \frac r s $, with $ r, s \in \mathbb N $. Is there an expression to obtain the values for $ x, y, u, v \in \mathbb N $, where $ \frac x y $ and $ \frac u v $ are irreducible, such that $ \frac a b = \frac x y + \frac u v $ ?"

Gosh! Here, it keeps saying it: "This question body does not meet our quality standards. Please make sure that it completely describes your problem - including what you have already tried - and is written using proper grammar."

Note: After adding the second paragraph, finally it went trough...

Comment: I think [meta-tag:support] tag should be changed as [meta-tag:discussion].

Comment: Done, @choco_addicted. Is it really such a bad question? Can't really grasp the meaning of the "-5" that it shows now... I couldn't send my question to the math forum, and it made all the sense.

Comment: As a human being reading your question, I am struck by the initial mention of $r,s$ as natural numbers but never mentioned again.  Possibly they are the intended $a,b$?  More than just clearing up that notational confusion should be done to make your Readers comfortable with replying in a useful manner.  You should indicate what your interest and involvement with the problem is, however briefly, so that no one wastes time explaining matters you already explored or understood.

Answer (score 14):

The literal answer is that it triggered some script that prevent posts that are judged to be likely not appropriate, based on lengths and some other criteria.

See [How to ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for advice on how to ask a good question.

That said, I cannot make sense of you question. One problem seems to be that it seems you change notation half-way.

Comment: Sorry but, after reading the "How to ask a good question?" section I could not get any idea of why the message didn't go through. Yes, the notation might be rather improvable, but the scripts cannot detect such subtle aspects of a question, that's pretty sure.

Comment: The main reason the question was auto-rejected should be that it is short and contains a lot of formulas in addition. But really mainly because it is short I think. The post I link to should explain you how you should write questions here. When  you follow this, as a by-product, you should not face this issue anymore.