# Can we have something like on-the-fly conversion of equation to MathJax?

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

New contributors can be seen unable to use MathJax when posting questions or answering them such as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3215057/is-my-solution-correct-trigonometry) before the edit by @[BPP](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/81595/bpp).

Would it be nice to have something that would find things that should be in MathJax and put the appropriate MathJax notation for it.

Maybe the MathJax tutorial be embedded in the page itself rather than having the user to click on a link and lose track of their question. I mean, I used to before I learnt MathJax on Math.SE

Comment: It seems unfeasible to do the on-the-fly conversion since whatever code is doing it would have to contend with all of the possible ways people not using LaTeX/MathJax might format their posts.

Comment: @user79161 Re: "Maybe the MathJax tutorial be embedded in the page itself rather than having the user to click on a link and lose track of their question", note that, depending on your browser & OS, you can usually force a link to open in a new tab or window. For example, with Firefox on Windows, right-clicking on a link shows a menu with the first $3$ choices being to open the link in a new tab, window or private window.

Comment: I would like to think that there's really no need for on-the-fly messages, since a better automated analysis of the content can be done when the post is submitted. There's already some kind of [script enforcing minimal standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23356), and I guess now the question is how can this be enhanced for specific purposes... through machine learning maybe? The hard-working staff of StackExchange should have something to say about this.

Comment: it's called the back button, I use it constantly.